# how to retrieve one to many relationship. Property [produks] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

**Operator Model**

```
public function produk()
{
    return this->hasMany(Produk::class);
}
```

**Produk Model**

```
public function operator()
{
    return this->belongsTo(Operator::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function operator()
{
    $data = Operator::all();
    return view('data', compact('data'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($data as $o)
    <tr>            
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $o->n_oper }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($data->produk as $p)
                {{ $p->n_prod }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Output**

> Exception
> Property [produk] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\oni\resources\views\data.blade.php)

what went wrong? please kindly assist me, im new to this

Comment: return $this >>>> Dont forget the $ it is type error here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a typo may be?? whatever, you are calling relationship on collection. relation belongs to an object.

```
@foreach ($data as $o)
    <tr>            
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $o->n_oper }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($o->produk as $p)
                {{ $p->n_prod }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

`data` is the collection. you have to call relationship on `$o`

and there's some other typos may be. you are missing the `$` sign in `$this` keyword. update your relationship

```
public function produk()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Produk::class);
}
```

and

```
public function operator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Operator::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling relation on collection. You have to call it on single instance like this

```
 @foreach ($data as $o)
<tr>            
    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
    <td>{{ $o->n_oper  }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach ($o->produk as $p)
            {{$p->n_prod}}
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And also change

```
    return this->hasMany(Produk::class);
```

this to

```
    return $this->hasMany(Produk::class);
```

and also for other relation like

```
return this->belongsTo(Operator::class);
```

to

```
return $this->belongsTo(Operator::class);
```

I hope its work.

Comment: it says error like this : Undefined constant "App\Models\this" (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\oni\resources\views\data.blade.php)

Comment: In your relation put $ with this keyword. like $this->